Which is the fastest Devata to give darshan in the shortest time or with the least repetition of mantras?
In general, the scriptures mention the exact time or number of repetitions of a mantra or ritual required to attain the darshan of a Devata. While factors such as shraddha (faith) and sadachara (proper conduct) also influence this, I am specifically looking for scriptural references that mention the name of the Devata who can give darshan with the least time or repetition count.
Could you provide references to such a Devata as mentioned in the scriptures?

There is no such a fastest devata or a hardest devata in the realm of Tantra. It is all depending on your Guru's Saktipāta (शक्तिपात).
Kulārnava Tantra(कुलार्णव तंत्र) [chapter-14], says that at the time of initiation the disciple receives not only Moola Mantra but also sakti(शक्ति) as given in the following sloka [14.38]:
शक्तिपातानुसारेण शिष्योनुग्रहमर्हति ।
यत्र शक्ति निपातता तत्र सिद्धिर्वजायते ॥ ३८ ॥

The disciple receives the Guru according to the impact of the Sakti
[Saktipāta]; where there is no impact of Sakti there is no fulfilment.॥ 38 ॥

Beware-1: Unless disciple receives guru blessings with enough impact of śaktipāta(शक्तिपात/transmission or conferring of spiritual energy upon one person by another), there is no siddhi (सिद्धि/fulfilment) is possible. Here guru should be a Siddha Guru (सिद्धिगुरु) the one who is competent and already attained siddhi known as Devata Vasyam(देवता वश्यम्) or Mantra siddhi(मंत्र सिद्धि) of the concerned Devata.
This Devatha Upāsana should be performed everyday or according to a solid time table. Based on your focus, dedication and perseverance you will taste success (Devatha Vasyam/देवता वश्यम्). This may take few weeks or few years, all in your hands particularly upon your Prārabdha Karma(प्रारब्ध कर्म) in this birth.
Kulārnava Tantra [chapter-15] speaks about conditions conducive to the success of japa as follows [sloka-113]:
तन्निष्ठस्तद्गतप्राणस्तच्चित्तस्तत्परायणः । 
तत्पदाथनुसन्धानं कुर्वन्‌ मनर जपेत्‌ प्रिये ॥ ११३ ॥ 

One should perform Japa with devotion to the Mantra, with life
dedicated to it, with mind centred upon it, wholly given to it,
following its meaning and meditating upon it.॥ 113 ॥ 


Mantra Mahodadhi [Chapter-24] says about what to do when Purashcharana is unsuccessful:
पुरश्चण एकस्मिन्कृते जन्मान्तराघतः | 
मन्त्रो यदि न सिद्धः स्यात्तदा तत्पुनराचरेत्‌ ॥ १२६॥

If by performing Purashcharana (पुरश्चरण), once the mantra does not
fructify due to sin of past past births, the sadhaka should repeat the
Purashcharana.॥ 126 ॥ 

Beware-2: This is the general complaint from sādhakas that even after completing the prescribed count of Japa if the mantra did not fructify then sādhaka should repeat Purashcharana until fructification of mantra. The reason is due to the karma of past births.
Beware-3: Kulārnava Tantra [chapter-15, sloka-100] describes Obstructive factors in the success of Japa is:
मनोऽन्यत्र शिवोऽन्यत्र शक्तिरन्यत्र मारुतः । 
न सिध्यति वरारोहे लक्षकोटिजपादपि ॥ १०० ॥ 

If the mind be in one place, Siva [passive consciousness] in another,
Sakti [active consciousness] in another and the life-breath in still
another, then even a crore of Japa, O Varārohe, would be useless.॥ 100 ॥ 

In order to expedite mantra fructification, it is wise to utilize the phenomenon such as solar and lunar eclipses without missing and perform purascarana during the entire period of eclipse. Mantra Mahodadhi [Chapter-24] says the following:
यद्वा समुद्रगामिन्यां नद्याभिन्दुरविग्रहे ।
स्पर्शान्मोक्षान्तमाजप्य जुहुयात्तद्दशांशत: ॥ १३०॥
विप्रान्सम्भोज्य नानान्नैर्मन्त्राणां सिद्धिमाप्नुयात्‌ ।
शश्वज्जपपरस्यापि सिध्यन्ति मनवोऽचिरात्‌ ॥ १३१॥  

At the time of solar or lunar eclipse, standing navel deep in some
river which falls in the ocean, the sādhaka should perform japa of
the Moola-mantra from the moment of touching of the eclipse till it
complete end. Then, perform Homa, 1/10th of the japa, and further
1/10th of Homa, feeding the Brāhmanās with various delicious food,
completes purascarana which bestows fructification. The mantras of a
person who performs incessant japa, also fructifies quickly. ॥ 130-131॥

-Mantra Mahodadhi Chapter-24

For instance, the one mantra which Devarishi Nārada taught and which was effectively used by Prince Dhruva was "Om Namo Bhagavate Vasudevaya". Having been advised, Dhruva started his meditation, and went without food and water for six months. Bhagavan Vishnu was pleased and appeared before Dhruva. Dhruva sang a poem praising Bhagavan Vishnu in 12 powerful verses, also known as Dhruva-stuti.
Thus, it was the Saktipāta of Devarishi Nārada, who did the mantra upadesa, had  caused to get Bhagavan Vishnu's darshana in just 6 months of time!
Good Luck!
